# Handling Events in React with Arrow Functions as variable or function?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React an encountered two different ways of writing event handling functions and do not know if they are somehow semantical identically or if it is just different sytax?

This seems more intuitive for me:

```js
clickHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    random: Math.random(),
  });
};
```

But in the book I am using they always do something like this:

```js
clickHandler2() {
  return () => {
    this.setState({
      random: Math.random(),
    });
  };
}
```

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/steffistuffel/pen/ExyGWQB?editors=1111) and all the behavior seems the same, especially `this` binding. Is it just different syntax for the complete same behavior?

Comment: Yes, it's just a different syntax. I prefer the first option because of reading reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some way it is different syntax, but second example where you return function back after executing `clickHandler2()` that is something called **Curry function** and you can see more about that here [in this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983).

Main benefit for `clickHandler2()` approach is that you can parametrize return function that will be executed when `onClick` occurs. This is good when you are looping through items and you need to pass some data (ex. `id`) if that code depends on any data.

```js
clickHandler2(id) {
  return () => {
     doSomething(id);
  };
}
```

```js
userIds.map((id) => <button onClick={this.clickHandler2(id)}>Click2</button>);
```

This is usually a case in lists. Other way for this to happen without using Curry function is to do this:

```js
clickHandler = (id) => {
  dosomething(id);
};
```

```js
userIds.map((id) => (
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      this.clickHandler(id);
    }}
  >
    Click2
  </button>
));
```